# pre-whitening ARIMA order of integration

Tags: time-series, modeling, arima

I am currently modelling a time series using an ARIMA model with transfer functions for the regressors.

In order to get a stationary dependent variable I need to take seasonal differences (at lag 52). For my regressor on the other hand, I would need to take differences at lag 1.

My question is now: Is is statistically valid that the order of integration differ between the two models?

Comment: No, you need to do difference both dependent and regressor in same order.

Comment: If we talk about pre-whitening of an input time series, does it then simply mean that we try to find appropriate p and q for the input time series or does it have to be more sophisticated (for example by also using regressors for the input)?